# Access icons from within QGIS plugin with relative paths?

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-plugins, icon, pyqt5

I have constructed a QGIS plugin using QGIS Plugin Builder 3.0.3.

Within my plugin, I need to load a .png file as a `Qicon` object.  What needs to be done for the plugin script to locate the .png file when it is run within QGIS?

For my situation, my .png file is called `line_1x.png`.

I have modified the `resources.qrc` within the plugin to show a reference to the icon as shown below:

```
<RCC>
<qresource prefix="/plugins/geomAttribute" >
    <file>attribute_table.png</file>
    <file>line_1x.png</file>
</qresource>
```

I compiled the resources file using the following command `pyrcc5 -o resources.py resources.qrc`.

Within my plugin python script I try to construct the QIcon object using:
`icon = QIcon('./line_1x.png')`

However, the plugin python script can't access the `line_1x.png` file.  When I use a full file path to the icon file instead of a relative path the icon image file is read properly.  Hence, using the following does work:
`icon = QIcon('C:/Users/pippi/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins/geomattribute/line_1x.png'`

How do a I get a QGIS plugin to read an image for an icon using a relative path?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The relative path for a file in a plugin is:

`:/plugins/PluginClassName/filename`

If in doubt, search for the path used for the `icon_path` in the `def initGui(self):` method.

Answer (score 0):

It is also possible to construct the path with:

```
self.plugin_dir + '/icon.png'
```

where self is the plugin class.

Answer (score 0):

you can try:

```
import os

QIcon(os.path.dirname(__file__) + "/line_1x.png")
```