# Setting a relative path to load a QML style in QGIS plugin

Tags: qgis-plugins, qgis-processing, pyqgis-3

I would like my plugin to apply a QML style to an output layer. This consists of three parts:

1. Packaging the QML file into the plugin.
2. Referring to the QML file using a relative path.
3. Setting the style on the output layer.

For number 1, I have saved my style as `default.qml` in a /styles/ subdirectory of the plugin, and I have added it like so into the `resources.qrc` file.

```
<RCC>
  <qresource prefix="/plugins/phylo_tree" >
     <file>styles/default.qml</file>
  </qresource>
</RCC>
```

I have then used `resources.qrc` to generate `resources.py` with pyrcc5

For number 2 - referring to the QML file by a relative path - my understanding is that the path should be `:plugins/phylo_tree/styles/default.qml`, as [mentioned in this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/297430/access-icons-from-within-qgis-plugin-with-relative-paths).

For number 3 - I have used the [code in this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/317450/qgis-3-4-how-to-add-qml-style-to-sink-in-processing) to add a style to the output layer, using the postProcessAlgorithm function. **This works if I use an absolute path to the QML file**, but *not* when I use the relative path `:plugins/phylo_tree/styles/default.qml`: When using the relative path, the operation completes without any error message, but no style is applied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply style from .qml file to layer using this code:

```
import os
style_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'styles/default.qml')
layer.loadNamedStyle(style_path)
```

You first import `os`.
Next get path to QML file by joining it`s relative path with plugin directory path.
In the end apply style to layer.

Comment: This is a completely different approach to the method I was trying to do, but it works! Thank you.